# Jquery Dialog doesnt show

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I want to generate a dialog box that gets password from user, here's a bit my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type='button' id='btnDelete' name='btnDelete' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRecord(".$row['ID'].")'/>
<div id="delete-dialog" style="display: none;" title="Delete Record">
    <label>Please type in admin's password:</label></br>
    <input type='password' size='25' id='inpAdminPassword'/>        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function deleteRecord(ID){
var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
if(answer == true){
     $( "#delete-dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#delete-dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,  
});
```

Somehow, the dialog box doesn't show, what must be missing?

I have also tried and included this code, but still it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#delete-dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,  
});
$("#delete-dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 255,
    width: 300,
    buttons: {
        "Delete": function() {
            var password = document.getElementById('sessionPW').value;
            var adminpw = document.getElementById('inpAdminPassword').value;
            alert(password);
            if(password == adminpw){
                window.location = "deleteThreat.php?threatID="+ID;
            }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just was trying your first solution and making the confirmation like this works for me:

js:

```
    $("#delete-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    });

    $("#open").click(function () {

        if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
            $("#delete-dialog").dialog("open");
        }


    });
```

html:

```
           <div id="delete-dialog" style="display: none;" title="Delete Record">
                <label>Please type in admin's password:</label></br>
                <input type='password' size='25' id='inpAdminPassword'/>        
            </div>

            <button id="open" >Open</button>
```

Comment: Did you put css code? Dialog still doesn't show. Are the js code inside the ready function?

Comment: It still doesn't show T.T how about jquery-ui version?

Comment: mmm try with this versions
jquery-1.11.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js

Comment: It doesn't work with my code, I guess I just have to make my own pop up div. He he